# Copy a Row if a Cell has Text

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro that copies a row if a particular cell in that row contains text (Column C), I have searched the internet and have found ones that deal with copying rows with specific text but I want to write one that copies it regardless of what text is contained in the cell.

For example if there are 30 rows but only 10 contain text in column C I want it to copy those 10 rows and paste them into a 'Action Summary' sheet.

At the moment I am using a conditional format to colour any cells without text and then filtering them out and copying the remaining rows but this is a little messy and I wondered if there was a cleaner way of doing it.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, you'd just have to check whether the cell is empty or not. Iterate through rows, then check on column c: `If Cells(x,3) <> "" Then...` where x represents your row.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Sub SmartCopy()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Action Summary")
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To N
        If s1.Cells(i, "C").Value = "" Then
        Else
            s1.Cells(i, "C").EntireRow.Copy s2.Cells(j, 1)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Update the *Sheet* names to match your requirements.

Comment: argh this is almost perfect it does exactly what I want but I need it to start searching from row 7 onwards, sorry I am really new to this!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub CopyNonBlank()
    Dim destWS As Worksheet ' Destination worksheet
    Set destWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Action Summary")
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    For Each cell In Range("C2:C32")
        If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then ' if cell is not empty lenght would be greater than 0
            destWS.Range("A" & i).Value = cell.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: This almost does what I want but I need to it copy the whole row into the summary sheet when column C has text in and there is a header line so it should start pasting them in row 2.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this then:

Dim y As Integer

```
y = 1
For x = 1 To 30
    If Sheets(1).Cells(x, 3) <> "" Then
        Do While Sheets("Action Summary").Cells(y, 3) <> ""
            y = y + 1
        Loop
        Sheets(1).Rows(x).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Action Summary").Rows(y)
        y = 1
    End If

Next x
```

it loops though the first 30 lines of sheet one, then upon finding a value in column c (which is column 3) it loops through the c column values of the "Action Summary" sheet incrementing the y variable until it finds a blank row to paste in, then it copies the entire row x of sheet 1 into the row y of the "Action Summary" sheet.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an If statement to determine if the cell contains text using something like:

```
If IsNumeric(rCell.Value) = False And _
IsError(rCell.Value) = False And _
IsDate(rCell.Value) = False Then
```

1st line checks the value is not a number, the next checks it is not an error message from a formula and the last checks it is not a date as these can be mistaken for text depending how they are formatted.

Then add your code to copy the row that you have already found.